# Вывод таблицы через json

Tags: javascript, база-данных, json, сервер, клиент-сервер

Мне нескем посоветоваться. Опыта и знаний не хватает.
Есть такая идея, список мероприятий вывести в таблицу, не хочу использовать аякс, что если php когда админ добавит мероприятие php mysql генерирует json файл обновится в папке на сервере и все клиенты его подхватят в дататабле.

Я просто думаю так меньше нагрузки на сервер и безопаснее будет или я не прав? можно еще создать файл версию js скрипт проверки если версия изменится то таблица пере загрузится.

Comment: Я правильно понял что вместо БД Вы хотите использовать json файл на Вашем хостинге?

Comment: у меня свой сервер. да

Comment: Как бы сам по себе подход имеет право на жизнь, но грубо говоря Вы изобретаете ~~велосипед~~ новую Базу Данных. В чём я вижу проблемы: _производительность ― любые методы перезаписи файла будут медленнее чем запись в БД, безопасность данных ― получается Ваши данные можно легко получить с хостинга, настройка сервера ― проблемы с правами на запись файлов, если на Вашем сервере всё хорошо, то представьте что будет если Вам нужно его сменить, поддержка ― сложнее будет найти ещё одного энтузиаста, который бы захотел работать с Вашим АПИ для записи данных, чем разработчика который дружит с MySQL_

Comment: да не подумал, спасибо.